# PhoneGap Build Android clearWatch() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, phonegap-build

I renamed title from **PGB Android watchAcceleration() doesn't work** to current title **PGB Android clearWatch() doesn't work**

Hi I am new in **PhoneGap Build** the method `getCurrentAcceleration()` works. I  installed plugin (device motion) in `config.xml` this plugin is **org.apache.cordova.device-motion**  0.2.11 version (plugin OK, because I get data from accelerometer). I typed `getCurrentAcceleration()` before and works. I get from `alert()` data: 
Acc X: -2.29...........

Acc Y: 3.52............

Acc Z: 8.73............, 
in below link I deleted `getCurrentAcceleration()` and 
`watchAcceleration()` doesn't work. Here is my code with `watchAcceleration()`
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PNpGbm
Physical device testing.

edit because I can't answer due to block
EDIT: So I solved `watchAcceleration()` but `clearWatch()` doesn't work

According to docs on github https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device-motion/blob/110b27671f454fcc28f7f642d55874ab0a7fe4a1/doc/index.md

> Access is via a global navigator.accelerometer object.
>   Although the object is attached to the global scoped navigator, it is not available until after the deviceready event.

`watchAcceleration()` must be in onDeviceReady() function 
...

Comment: solved issue with `watchAcceleration()` but instead `clearWatch()` doesn't work
more info in question

Comment: your JS code has issues.